# how to set the distance between left view and right view in the carousel

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

Is there any way to change the distance between the left and the right view in carousel .

I've tried with setting the perspective but it makes my view small.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need following delegate method to change the distance.
When delegate ask value for `iCarouselOptionSpacing` return suitable value..

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionWrap:
        {
            return YES;
        }
        case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
        {
            //This is the spacing, return the value
            return 1.5f;
        }
        default:
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but i think that it is called when we use the custom carousel type and in my case the carousel type is rotary when I implemented its not changing any thing

Comment: i used scrolling example of icarousel and changed its type to `iCarouselTypeRotary`. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The number of visible views just depends on the size of the items relative to the screen, the spacing and the number of visible views.

```
-(CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value

{

    if (option == iCarouselOptionCount)
    {
        return 5;
    }
    return value;
}
```